# Topic challenge: how alien can a visual sense organ be?

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

We no longer have [regular topic challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/should-we-end-the-topic-challenges) events, but ocasional one-off challenges happen from time to time.

With the latest *eye* question I noticed the selection of **alien visual system** ideas we’ve had thus far, and I added a [vision](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vision) to a few that I recalled.

I’d like to further muse over and discuss just **how different a visual sense could be**, challenging every component in the architecture and looking into more novel ways in which such a sense could be implemented.

Note to that end I rever to *vision* rather than “eye” because [Hal Clement writes of aliens with a more novel implementation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_to_Critical).

Just asking that is too broad. So it occured to me to bring it up as a topic challenge, and then summarize the results on a meta post.

Comment: I like this idea and will be happy to participate

Comment: Let me guess: “anatomically correct [Trawliberg Terror](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trollenberg_Terror)”?  No, wait; [that’s been done](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28921/evolution-of-the-giant-eye-creatures).

Comment: oh, ha ha my sides, they be splitting