# Topic challenge: alien geometry

Tags: discussion, tags, challenge

I propose an [alien-geometry](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-geometry) topic challenge.

Its often hard to tweak the mathematics of a world (for example, you can't really make 2+2=5 in a reasonable way), but one way you can is by tweaking the geometry. This can lead to many interesting implications, including [chemical](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/what-would-the-periodic-table-of-a-4-dimensional-universe-look-like), [biological](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12378/infinite-flat-world), and even [cultural](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101804/how-can-orientation-discriminating-people-keep-their-views-when-it-turns-out-the) implications.

Here are [some examples of 3-manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-manifold#Important_examples_of_3-manifolds) for inspiration; (3-manifolds are similar to our world locally). ([4-manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-manifold) are also similar if you include time.)

Also, the use of [quotient spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) helps too.

EDIT: It appears to be finished. If someone wants to propose another tag challenge, go ahead.

Comment: Didn't we drop the topic challenges? ...And [a search](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3483/6986) says yes and no.

Comment: @Frostfyre we dropped *periodic* topic challenges, but if somebody wants to call for one from time to time, that seems fine to me.

Comment: I don't think I had previously noticed that we *have* an alien-geometry tag. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Which is what the question I linked says.

Comment: Of all the topic challenges to try to renew interest in the subject you pick [tag:alien-geometry]? I don't even know what that means...

Comment: @kingledion You could try one (although I'm not sure what the rules are if multiple people want to do topic challenges).

Comment: @PyRulez I'm trying to do this one! I can't think of what to ask about alien geometry. Its so....alien...

Comment: @kingledion Browsing over the other questions might help. One simple thing to do is to just "glue" things together. Or you can just ask a question about one of the worlds asked about in the other questions (for example, you could ask what political system would be best in the infinite flat world).

Comment: What exactly is a topic challenge?

Comment: @adaliabooks uhm, I guess it means your challenged to write posts with this tag?

Comment: @PyRulez I thought that was probably it but wanted to check... thanks

Comment: Dunno, there are so many variations of geometry already in our world that it may suffice to take a trip to https://math.stackexchange.com/ rather than inconvenience distant aliens.
It may be easier worldbuilding on `alien-[empirical science]` tags than using purely abstract disciplines.

Or, perhaps, asking about the physics of worlds where the only possible triangles are Penrose triangles, and the only possible bottles are Klein bottles...

Comment: @NofP Even though many different geometries "exist" abstractly, the cultural implications of such geometries are only realized if a universe if based off them. Asking about world building of math.se would be off topic.

Comment: @PyRulez  my apologies, I must sound very thick, but all the geometries we know do have applications in our world today, including basic construction science, data analysis, physics, chemistry, social sciences, etc... Euclidean geometry is but a drop of the ocean of things what we do today with geometry. Unless you are thinking of "aliens that replace [mainstream geometry] with [other geometry] in [specific field]".

Comment: @NofP, Ah, you may want to take a look at the [tag wiki](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/alien-geometry/info). [tag:alien-geometry] means we replace Euclidean (ignoring general relativity) geometry of our universe with some other geometry (such as the projective plane or something), no more, no less. I suppose the term "alien-geometry" is slightly misleading, since these geometries where discovered by humans. (It was named that based on the [TV Tropes article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlienGeometries) by the same name.)

Comment: Aha,ok! All clear now.

Comment: For what it's worth we stopped holding *periodic* topic challenges and when we did so we mentioned specifically that users are free to create their own when they choose to do so.  Not sure you will get a ton of support/interest on alien geometry but stranger things have happened here :)

Comment: @James Well, most the questions have been asked by *me*, so...

Maybe after this challenge, someone will have a more successful challenge.

Comment: @James I also think people participated in the "officially sanctioned" challenges more as well (since I'm not the first one top propose a topic challenge out of the blue).

Comment: @PyRulez What is the time period of this challenge?

Comment: @user_194421 until they remove it from the sidebar, I guess.

Comment: @user_194421 [featured] tags last 2 weeks before the Community user automatically untags them.

Comment: @Riker are you sure? I think this had been featured for more than two weeks at this point (not that I'm complaining).

Comment: @PyRulez hm, maybe 4 weeks then. I know it auto-untags though. We'll find out in 11 more days.